# Error adjustAdaptiveCoef

Tags: android

I have the following code in order to wait for a while:

```
t1=new Date();
seg1=t1.getSeconds();
seg2=seg1;
while((seg2-seg1)<5){
  t1=new Date();
  seg2=t1.getSeconds();
}
```

If i execute it for many times, the app gets frozen and i get the following error:

04-01 17:04:16.001      510-513/com.example.moya.serviciobroadcastmanager E/dalvikvm﹕ adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
04-01 17:04:16.001      510-513/com.example.moya.serviciobroadcastmanager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 594K, 33% free 10338K/15232K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 21ms
04-01 17:04:16.001      510-789/com.example.moya.serviciobroadcastmanager D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
04-01 17:04:16.102      510-513/com.example.moya.serviciobroadcastmanager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1362K, 33% free 10339K/15232K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 28ms
04-01 17:04:16.152      510-513/com.example.moya.serviciobroadcastmanager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 541K, 33% free 10340K/15232K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 23ms

How can i solve it? I don't want to use Thread.sleep();

UPDATE:
I have figured it out using System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: `I don't want to use Thread.sleep()` why?

Comment: @F43nd1r I am receiving intents in broadcast receiver at the same time, and, i don't know why, Thread.sleep() doesn't work well. Anyway, i have figured it out using System.currentTimeMillis.